# Difference/When to use Row and Column Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have a few questions about row vs. column vectors (MSc CS Thesis):

- What is the standard in computer science (if not mentioned explicitly)? Row or column vectors?
- If I write "vector $\mathbf{x}$ is the input data" -> Is this assumed to be column or row vector?
- If there is no notation standard in CS, what is the defacto standard which major programming libraries/frameworks/tools use? If I define a vector there (e.g. x := [1 2 3]) do I get a column or row vector?  Because of this kind of notation I assume you get a row vector?
- I ask this questions because I see in Neural Network literature often things like Weight Matrix multiplied by an input value vector. I see 2 notations in papers: $\mathbf{Wx}$ and $\mathbf{Wx^T}$ and I (guess?) that this is transpose is needed because some publications assume that $\mathbf{x}$ is a column vector and others assume a row vector?
- Is it general accepted to choose between row or columnvector to get condensed formulas depending on your operations (avoid overkill of transposes)?

Thanks

Comment: The distinction is only relevant if you use matrix multiplication in some way, and only is useful if all occurring "tensors" (multilinear objects, like linear maps or bilinear forms) have rank $\leq2$.